# Left aligning cell contents in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

If you compile the code given below, then the row which states "Average Pre-Authentication Response Time" is justified with a lot of spacing between the words. I want it to be left-aligned. Also, if a line breakage is required, then can I ask LaTeX to prefer keeping the word as a whole and shifting it to the next line if space is available? In this case, there is a hyphen and the word is breaking, but there is enough space for the whole word to shift down.

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
%% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
%% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%


\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

%% for inline R code: if the inline code is not correctly parsed, you will see a message
\newcommand{\rinline}[1]{SOMETHING WRONG WITH knitr}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{blue!25}
\colorlet{fail}{red}
\colorlet{passPoor}{yellow}
\colorlet{passGood}{green!50}
\colorlet{optimal}{green}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \small
  \centering
  \caption{Brief overview of the Results}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{XX}
    %\hline
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{tableheadcolor}
    Metrics for machine  & \textbf{Result} \\
    %\hline
    \midrule
    Failure Rate & 0.00\% \\
    Lorema LoremLore Lore & 0.0 sec \\
    Average Pre-Authentication (ASD) Response Time & 0.0 sec \\
    Overall Result & \cellcolor{passGood}Passed \\
    %\hline
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:overviewOld}%
\normalsize
\end{table}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `>{\raggedright}XX` so the first column will be typeset ragged right. Remove the `flushleft` environment around `table` which does nothing good.

Comment: By default, the material in an `X` column is typeset fully justified. If you want to have it typeset ragged-right while preserving the ability of TeX to hyphenate words, load the `ragged2e` package and use the column specification `>{\RaggedRight}XX`. (Note the two uppercase R's in "RaggedRight".)

Comment: @Mico: I used > \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{{\RaggedRight}XX} after adding the package. It gives an Error:  Illegal pream-token (\RaggedRight): `c' used.

Any comments?

Comment: You're missing a `>` symbol before `{\RaggedRight}XX`. (Think of the `>` symbol as "pushing" its argument, `{\RaggedRight}`, into the specs for the column type `X`...)

Comment: Ah. I thought you had copied a prompt by mistake. This seems to have solved the first part. Any ideas on how I can go about preferring a new line instead of a word-break?

Comment: If you do *not* want to allow hyphenation in a ragged-right environment, use `\raggedright` instead of `\RaggedRight`. However, be prepared for some fairly short and ragged-looking lines...

Comment: @Mico That worked. If you want, you can copy your comments into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @AlastorMoody - Sure, will do. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting some of the information contained in the comments to the posting:

- Text typeset in a column of type `X` is "fully justified". Depending on the (non)availabability of permissible hyphenation break points, this can lead to unsightly columns with either too little or too much text squeezed into the available space.
- To typeset the text material in the first column of the table in "ragged-right" manner *without* permitting hyphenation, replace the column specifier `X` with

  ```
  >{\raggedright}X
  ```

  Think of the `>` symbol as "pushing"  its argument, `\raggedright`, into the column specification of `X`.
- A downside of using the `\raggedright` specification is that the resulting material can look, well, extremely ragged. To enable ragged-right typesetting while also allowing LaTeX to insert line breaks at hyphenation points within words, be sure to load the `ragged2e` package (which is already done in your code) and to use the column specification

  ```
  >{\RaggedRight}X
  ```

  Note the two uppercase-R letters.